# Does anyone know why I've been getting thin rectangular outlines all over my desktop?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

[image: Rectangular lines on my desktop]

These lines have been appearing and increasing in number.

Comment: Are they gone when restarting your system or are they always there ?

Comment: They go when I restart. Later new lines start appearing one by one.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an OSX Failure. You should try to reinstall the operating system.